# ways to decrease memory usage and optimize your code in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, memory-management

I am running this code on a windows 7x64 system with 4 GB of physical RAM available:

```
fileID1 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T11.bin','r');
A1 = fread(fileID1);
fclose(fileID1);
fileID2 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T12_real.bin','r');
A2 = fread(fileID2);
fclose(fileID2);
fileID3 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T12_imag.bin','r');
A3 = fread(fileID3);
fclose(fileID3);
fileID4 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T13_real.bin','r');
A4 = fread(fileID4);
fclose(fileID4);
fileID5 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T13_imag.bin','r');
A5 = fread(fileID5);
fclose(fileID5);
fileID6 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T22.bin','r');
A6 = fread(fileID6);
fclose(fileID6);
fileID7 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T23_real.bin','r');
A7 = fread(fileID7);
fclose(fileID7);
fileID8 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T23_imag.bin','r');
A8 = fread(fileID8);
fclose(fileID8);
fileID9 = fopen ('D:\A\B\T3\T33.bin','r');
A9 = fread(fileID9);
```

The problem is it encounters the error:

```
Error using fread
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in freeman2coponent (line 24)
A4 = fread(fileID4);
```

each of the nine files that I am trying to open is a file of size 159 MB and it has 162875472x1 double elements. And I need the value of a pixel and its neighbors in all of the nine files simultaneously to do my computations.
Is there an efficient way to do this? I want my code not take too much time and memory
I have opened one of files with binary viewer and these are the contents of the file:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you cast the pixel values to a uint8? that might save some memory. Also, look into matfile(), which allows you to only load parts of variables as you need them (but may be a bit slow).

Comment: @adalca is completely right, actually you save a lot of memory by casting to uint8 – your 159 MB file takes up 1243 MB in memory after all. Memory mapping is a good idea, too, but in this case not `matfile` but `memmapfile` is what you need.

Comment: good call on memmapfile - I haven't used it too much so the first thing that came to mind instead was matfile.

Answer (score -1):

if you cast all values to uint8, be sure to cast it back to double before doing any computation.

matlab has no promotion, so if you take the sum of the a lot if uint8s, it will saturate at 256, and if you take the mean of multiple integers, you won't get the fraction.

a better way to do it might be only load a small block of the file then fread blcok by block

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  The context of the question suggests that the data are already images, and so there isn't a need to cast back to `double`.  The resulting calculations themselves can be `double`, but there is no need to keep the images as `double`.

Comment: @user3528438 I can use nested loops and fseek to read blocks of file each time but it will slow the code alot!